# How can have d3.js recognize a hexcolor from a .csv as the appropriate hex color for a set of boxes?

Tags: d3.js

I have this code which loads my .CSV data successfully.

```
      // Read the CSV file and parse the data
      d3.csv("Data.csv").then(function(data) {
        // Store the parsed data in the variable.
        var parsedData = data;

        // Convert the data to the format expected by the visualization code.
        var nodeData = parsedData.map(function(d) {
            console.log("color: ", d.color); // add this line to check the color value
            return {
                occ: d.occ,
                position: [+d.x * smaller_width, +d.y * smaller_height],
                parentPosition: [+d.parent_x * smaller_width, +d.parent_y * smaller_height],
                color: d.color
            };
        });
```

Then, later on I have code the puts boxes on my visualization using the coordinates on the CSV and labels them using the text on the CSV. I would like to also color the boxes using the hex color saved on the CSV, but this seems to not work for me. Below is my attempt at the code.

```
            d3.select(this)
                .append("rect")
                .classed("rect", true)
                .attr("occ", `rect-${d.occ}`)
                .attr("x", -10)
                .attr("y", -20)
                .attr("width", 20)
                .attr("height", 40)
                .style("fill", `text-${d.color}`) // I've also tried just ${d.color}, just color, and just d.color, and hundreds other variations... I can't seem to make it work.
                .style("paint-order", "stroke fill markers");
```

I tried chaning the way that the color is called but I can't seem to figure out the syntax. Around my code I have calls for text, but those didn't seem to work. I wonder if the problem is that the style and the attr functions are different in how they handle d.elements.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `.style("fill",` text-${d.color}`)` into `.style("fill", d.color)` will do the trick. :)